# Works two scripts in one browser

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have two scripts. The first opens the browser and goes to the desired site.

```
drv = webdriver.Chrome()
drv.get('http://some_site')
```

The second script fills the web form on the site opened by the first script.

```
drv.find_element_by_xpath('//some_xpath')
```

I also have a Tkinter window with two buttons.
It is very necessary for me that I could open the browser through the first script by clicking on one button, and by running the second button I could run the second script to fill out the web form.

With VBA I can do it easily with two subs in one file a define `public driver`

```
Public Sub browser_open()
Set driver= New ChromeDriver
driver.Start "chrome", "http://some_site"
driver.get "/"
End Sub
```

and continue work with driver in another sub

```
sub WebFormFill
driver.FindElementByClass("input-text").Value = "Some text"
end sub
```

But in Python  i cant do like code above

In Python Selenium, you can launch the browser through a separate script, and then in the second script use the `driver` from the first script and continue working on filling out web forms by running the second .py script?

Comment: What's the question? Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think you can do this but you can put the entire second script in a `def functionName():` and call `functionName()` at the end of the first script. Just make sure to import the second file into the first one as if it’s a library. Say the second file was called `hi.py` you would type `import hi`.

Comment: I am new to Python, but it’s very surprising for me that you cannot do what you can in VBA Selenium